# Typescript enum as static object property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum:

```
export enum QueryType {
 'X' = 'OBJECT_X',
 'Y' = 'OBJECT_Y',
    ...
}
```

I want a static object member to be query type, so I can use `MyObject.ObjectQueryType.X` in my code but this does not work. How can I do this?

```
class MyObject {
    public static ObjectQueryType = QueryType;
}
```

Comment: it should work see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAimwCcCeAVJAHYUDeBYAUFAOQAaRUAvMQPIBCAUgKIDCKA+mQDQHECa5VInSas2-bvgC+BAgGMANgEMAzsqgBZJNQBGAK2CyALjh5Qz6MNvkBLWVGWHFh21B36jcRKgxYqn5GiYANwE0vhyAPYgyhHywAB08hEA5gAUmm4GhvGZHvABPvEkAJQh+LJRMXGJKelaelk5DXlegQm8pQRAA), what's the error?

Comment: this works fine